# What should be the correct frequency of daily data?

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I have a time series which represents the amount of a certain product sold throughout the year 2018 (`from 2018/01/01 to 2018/12/31`); is it correct to think of a frequency of 7 observations per cycle? and if so, what is my cycle? one week? I try to understand this in order to decompose my time series avoiding the error `Error in decompose(tsData) : time series has no or less than 2 periods`. This is my `R script` and my `data`.

```
library(forecast)
library(sweep)
library(timetk)

Data <- read.delim("R Project/Dataset/MyData.txt")
DataFrame <- data.frame(Data, 
                        Date = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), 
                                   by = "day"))
inds <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day")
tsData <- ts(Data, start = c(2018, as.numeric(format(inds[1], "%j"))), 
                   frequency = 365)
print(tsData)
plot(tsData)
Axis(inds, side = 1, at = seq(inds[1], tail(inds, 1) + 60,
           by = "1 months"), format = "%b %Y")
comp = decompose(tsData)
#comp = stl(tsData)
plot(comp)
fit <- auto.arima(tsData)
fore <- forecast(fit, h = 15, level = 99.5)
plot(fore, xaxt = "n")
Axis(inds, side = 1, at = seq(inds[1], tail(inds, 1) + 60, by = "1 months"), 
                     format = "%b %Y")
```

---

This is `MyData.txt` file

```
Daily Data
0
2621
3407
3644
3569
1212
0
0
4473
3885
3671
3641
1453
0
4182
3812
3650
3444
3557
1612
0
4004
3631
3342
3203
3424
1597
0
4280
3644
3642
3696
3793
1753
0
4416
3935
3522
3544
3569
1649
0
3871
3442
3144
3158
3693
1780
0
4322
3682
3499
3279
3485
1716
0
4255
3713
3470
3673
3983
1931
0
4771
3986
3833
3501
3620
1710
0
4407
3799
3654
3332
3693
1780
0
0
4574
4016
3748
3559
1625
0
4548
3726
2780
0
0
122
0
5005
4300
3772
3929
3917
2021
0
4820
4117
3668
3664
3639
1742
0
4473
4151
3844
3499
3736
1838
0
4346
3693
3297
3327
3639
1773
0
4519
0
4352
4079
4143
1970
0
4693
4018
3679
3838
3606
1601
0
0
4289
4011
3742
3710
1781
0
4186
3707
3600
3484
3702
1747
0
4195
3838
3504
3609
3934
1943
0
0
5243
4754
4164
4121
1854
0
0
5173
4518
3875
3889
1904
0
5105
4056
4186
4079
3953
1846
0
4543
4341
4013
2998
4048
1767
0
0
4317
5260
5185
4969
2046
0
5683
5004
4567
4542
4266
2065
0
4357
5281
4830
4510
0
1567
0
5818
4906
4518
4218
4275
2074
0
5005
4645
4543
4558
4574
2129
0
4755
0
4458
3845
3746
1689
0
4285
3476
3447
2959
3470
1584
0
0
4159
3881
3533
3360
1643
0
4152
3748
3329
3112
3303
1790
0
3852
4190
3482
3313
3400
1582
0
4042
3706
3451
3137
3178
1518
0
4077
3754
3429
3369
3307
1467
0
3918
3620
3442
3302
3168
1630
0
3967
3707
3397
3294
3314
1646
0
4196
3812
3478
3111
3113
1411
0
0
3717
3501
3282
3366
1554
0
3737
3428
3028
2960
2977
1513
0
3608
3306
2941
2918
3238
1543
0
0
3959
3678
3367
3237
1024
0
0
4057
3562
3344
3367
1602
0
3784
3581
3395
2948
3009
1446
0
3676
3276
3112
3125
3133
1502
0
4200
4027
3739
3531
3222
2
0
4446
4342
4066
3811
2932
1643
0
4587
4534
4146
3994
3350
1400
0
1248
0
4248
4629
4346
1844
0
168
```

Comment: provide an example of your actual data, what you tried and exact error you got (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cccnrc - my actual data is the `Daily Data frame`; i'm try to do forecast to my data, so, first i try to decompose my time series, but instead I get the error `Error in decompose(myzoo) : time series has no or less than 2 periods`, so, i'm try to 'adjust' the `frequency` changing the value of `365`
for another value that makes sense.

Comment: provide an example of "MyData.txt"

Comment: @cccnrc - done, it is worth mentioning that the zero values ​​correspond to the sales made on holidays and Sundays.

Comment: This might help: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `frequency =` parameter in `ts()` function indicates the number of observations before pattern repetition. If you set a seasonality of 365 (1 year) with 1 year of data it will have only 1 period and so `decompose()` tells you: `time series has no or less than 2 periods`.
As you said "7 observations per cycle", you may want to set frequency equal to 7. Or if you want to analyze year seasonality put more data in `tsData`.

Just change:

```
# ....
tsData <- ts(Data, start = c(2018, as.numeric(format(inds[1], "%j"))), frequency = 365)
# ...
```

to :

```
# ...
### weekly seasonality
tsData <- ts(Data, start = c(2018, as.numeric(format(inds[1], "%j"))), frequency = 7)
#...
```

and now decompose works:

```
comp = decompose(tsData) # NO ERROR
### get the plot
plot(comp)
# ... rest of your code ...
```

here the plot:

[image: plot(comp) result]

---

**EDIT** on your comment:

The X-axis on the plot depends on how you declare the start, please have a look at [ts documentation](https://otexts.com/fpp2/ts-objects.html).

If you want to have the 2018 year value you can simply use (see documentation) `autoplot()` :

```
# ... rest of code ...
autoplot(tsData)
# ... rest of code ...
```

that is also highly customizable, if you want to know how to customize the plot (made through `ggplot2` package) just have a look at [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.1.1) and all the posts on this blog etc.

[image]

Comment: when i set the `frequency = 7` the time label of `plot(tsData)` goes from `2020 2030 2040 2050 2060 2070`, why is this happening? I think it should be from `2018.01 2018.02 ... 2018.11 2018.12`.